# Creating a list of avalible Timeslots based on a list LocalDateTime objects and a List of taken Timeslots with Streams

Tags: java, list, java-stream, localdatetime

I have a `List<Timeslot>` that contains entity `Timeslot` with the following fields:

1. `timeslot_id`;
2. `day`;
3. `start_time`;
4. `end_time`.

For example, this *list* contains two records:

- `start_time` of the first record equals `9:00` and `end_time` equals `10:00`.
- `start_time` of second object equals `10:00` and `end_time` equals `11:00`.

And the second *list* contains timestamps `List<LocalDateTime>`:

```
[2022-04-16T08:00, 2022-04-16T09:00, 2022-04-16T10:00, 2022-04-16T11:00, 
 2022-04-16T12:00, 2022-04-16T13:00, 2022-04-16T14:00, 2022-04-16T15:00]
```

I need to create a third `List<Timeslot>` that will contain `Timeslot`s except this two from the first list.

In this case, as a result, the *third list* should contain six objects of `Timeslot` class.

`start_time` of first should equal `2022-04-16T08:00` and end_time `2022-04-16T09:00`. I.e. the difference between `start_time` and `end_time` for every other *timeslot* is **one hour**.

So, the **result** constructed from the list of *timestamps* provided above should contain six objects:

- `start_time` is `8:00`, `end_time` is `9:00`.
- `start_time` is `11:00`, `end_time` is `12:00`.
- `start_time` is `12:00`, `end_time` is `13:00` ... and so on.

I the objects for with `start_time` `9:00` and `10:00` will not be present in the third list because they  are booked already (*present in the first list*).

I tried to create the *third list* using Java Streams, which should compare fields `start_time` and `end_time` with timestamps from the *second list*.

I've tried this, but the resulting list is always empty:

```
List<Timeslot> availableSlots = query.stream()
    .filter(timeslot -> timestamps.contains(timeslot.getStartTime()))
    .toList();
```

**Timeslot** class:

```
@Entity(name = "timeslot")
public class Timeslot {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "timeslot_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "day", columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDateTime day;
    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private LocalDateTime endTime;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;
    @Column(name = "is_recorded")
    private Boolean isRecorded;
}
```

Comment: How does your constructor(s) look like for the `Timeslot` class? Do you have `hashCode` and `equals` implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've simplified your `Timeslot` class for this problem (*for demonstration purposes*) since for this task you primarily concern about the *start time* and *end time* of each *timeslot*.

My approach is to create a set of `LocalDateTime` objects by extracting the *start time* from each *timeslot* that is already taken (represented by your first list).

Then create a stream over the `query` list and filter the date-time object that are not present in the set. Then create a *timeslot* using each date-time object as a *start time* (*end time* = *start time* + 1 hour). And collect all the stream elements into a *list*.

*Note*: terminal operation `toList()` creates an immutable list, you can obtain a mutable list by applying `collect(Collectors.toList())` instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<LocalDateTime> query =
        List.of(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 8, 00),
                LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 9, 00),
                LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 10, 00),
                LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 11, 00),
                LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 12, 00),
                LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 13, 00),
                LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 14, 00),
                LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 15, 00));

    List<Timeslot> timeslots = // timeslots that already taken
        List.of(new Timeslot(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 9, 00),
                             LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 10, 00)),
                new Timeslot(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 10, 00),
                             LocalDateTime.of(2022, 04, 16, 11, 00)));
    
    Set<LocalDateTime> takenStartTime = timeslots.stream()
        .map(Timeslot::getStartTime)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    List<Timeslot> availableSlots = query.stream()
        .filter(dateTime -> !takenStartTime.contains(dateTime))
        .map(dateTime -> new Timeslot(dateTime, dateTime.plusHours(1)))
        .toList();
    
    availableSlots.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Simplified dummy `Timeslot` class

```
public class Timeslot {
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    private LocalDateTime endTime;
    
    // constructor, getters, toString()
}
```

**Output**

```
Timeslot{start_time=2022-04-16T08:00, end_time=2022-04-16T09:00}
Timeslot{start_time=2022-04-16T11:00, end_time=2022-04-16T12:00}
Timeslot{start_time=2022-04-16T12:00, end_time=2022-04-16T13:00}
Timeslot{start_time=2022-04-16T13:00, end_time=2022-04-16T14:00}
Timeslot{start_time=2022-04-16T14:00, end_time=2022-04-16T15:00}
Timeslot{start_time=2022-04-16T15:00, end_time=2022-04-16T16:00}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Answer by Alexander Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71897056/642706) is very good. Here is an alternative, as food for thought.

By the way, your `day` field is redundant. You know both the date and date-time from the starting `LocalDateTime`. I suggest eliminating that from your model.

## Add `TimeSlot#contains` method

Let's define your `TimeSlot` class more briefly as a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). And I will use `UUID` as an identifier, to not fiddle with counting integers.

```java
record TimeSlot( UUID id , LocalDateTime start , LocalDateTime end ) {}
```

The trick is to add a `contains` method, telling the caller whether a particular `LocalDateTime` happens to lay within the bounds of our time slot. We use Half-Open approach, where the span of time is defined with the beginning being *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

Notice that “not before” is a shorter way of saying “is equal to or is later than”.

```java
record TimeSlot( UUID id , LocalDateTime start , LocalDateTime end )
{
    boolean contains ( LocalDateTime localDateTime )
    {
        return ( ( ! localDateTime.isBefore( this.start ) ) && localDateTime.isBefore( this.end ) );
    }
}
```

Sample data.

```java
List < TimeSlot > timeslots =
        List.of(
                new TimeSlot(
                        UUID.fromString( "0500ce28-ad96-43d0-9b3d-b907cadd27f9" ) ,
                        LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 9 , 00 ) ,
                        LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 10 , 00 )
                ) ,
                new TimeSlot(
                        UUID.fromString( "887d72df-4787-4974-ab6d-f2a46cb7d7af" ) ,
                        LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 10 , 00 ) ,
                        LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 11 , 00 )
                )
        );
```

And some sample inputs.

```java
List < LocalDateTime > inputs =
        List.of(
                LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 8 , 00 ) ,
                LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 9 , 00 ) ,
                LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 10 , 00 ) ,
                LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 11 , 00 ) ,
                LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 12 , 00 ) ,
                LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 13 , 00 ) ,
                LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 14 , 00 ) ,
                LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , 04 , 16 , 15 , 00 )
        );
```

Make a new list of `TimeSlot` objects, skipping over spans of time take by our existing `TimeSlot` objects.

```java
List < TimeSlot > resultingTimeSlots = new ArrayList <>( inputs.size() );
```

Loop the input `LocalDateTime` objects. For each, ask each of the original time slots if they happen to contain that date-time value. If so, add that found time slot to our list. If not, create a new `TimeSlot` object using the input `LocalDateTime` as the start, and assuming the end should be an hour later.

```
for ( LocalDateTime input : inputs )
{
    Optional < TimeSlot > hit = timeslots.stream().filter( timeSlot -> timeSlot.contains( input ) ).findAny();
    resultingTimeSlots.add( hit.orElse( new TimeSlot( UUID.randomUUID() , input , input.plusHours( 1 ) ) ) );
}
```

That code could be optimized. Using [`Optional#orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) is actually executing a `new TimeSlot` on every loop of our `for`, whether needed or not.

We can verify this behavior by adding a compact constructor to our record.

```java
record TimeSlot( UUID id , LocalDateTime start , LocalDateTime end )
{
    TimeSlot
    {
        System.out.println( "running constructor for " + id );
    }

    boolean contains ( LocalDateTime localDateTime )
    {
        return ( ( ! localDateTime.isBefore( start ) ) && localDateTime.isBefore( end ) );
    }
}
```

Let’s replace that with [`Optional#orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)) while transforming our `new TimeSlot` into a lambda that implements the required `Supplier` interface. This change means a new `TimeSlot` object will be instantiated only when we truly need it.

```java
for ( LocalDateTime input : inputs )
{
    Optional < TimeSlot > hit = timeslots.stream().filter( timeSlot -> timeSlot.contains( input ) ).findAny();
    resultingTimeSlots.add( hit.orElseGet( ( ) -> new TimeSlot( UUID.randomUUID() , input , input.plusHours( 1 ) ) ) );
}
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "resultingTimeSlots.size(): " + resultingTimeSlots.size() );
System.out.println( "resultingTimeSlots.containsAll( timeslots ): " + resultingTimeSlots.containsAll( timeslots ) );
System.out.println( resultingTimeSlots );
```

When run.

```
running constructor for 0500ce28-ad96-43d0-9b3d-b907cadd27f9
running constructor for 887d72df-4787-4974-ab6d-f2a46cb7d7af
running constructor for ce2b9c66-ef69-4ecd-a451-7a51ebbb259e
running constructor for c77cf83f-5ea8-4da3-9a44-104a56f4de03
running constructor for 139280b6-20c4-4428-b2cb-80717a00756b
running constructor for 1d219e16-0513-466e-9b84-091312e4ff5e
running constructor for 4b0b6c11-c6ae-4e04-a8fe-6c1245f7e80b
running constructor for 1ccdbd7f-ff4c-4d7d-b900-54d14898a50f
resultingTimeSlots.size(): 8
resultingTimeSlots.containsAll( timeslots ): true
[TimeSlot[id=ce2b9c66-ef69-4ecd-a451-7a51ebbb259e, start=2022-04-16T08:00, end=2022-04-16T09:00], TimeSlot[id=0500ce28-ad96-43d0-9b3d-b907cadd27f9, start=2022-04-16T09:00, end=2022-04-16T10:00], TimeSlot[id=887d72df-4787-4974-ab6d-f2a46cb7d7af, start=2022-04-16T10:00, end=2022-04-16T11:00], TimeSlot[id=c77cf83f-5ea8-4da3-9a44-104a56f4de03, start=2022-04-16T11:00, end=2022-04-16T12:00], TimeSlot[id=139280b6-20c4-4428-b2cb-80717a00756b, start=2022-04-16T12:00, end=2022-04-16T13:00], TimeSlot[id=1d219e16-0513-466e-9b84-091312e4ff5e, start=2022-04-16T13:00, end=2022-04-16T14:00], TimeSlot[id=4b0b6c11-c6ae-4e04-a8fe-6c1245f7e80b, start=2022-04-16T14:00, end=2022-04-16T15:00], TimeSlot[id=1ccdbd7f-ff4c-4d7d-b900-54d14898a50f, start=2022-04-16T15:00, end=2022-04-16T16:00]]
```

If you want to skip the original items, change that `for` loop to this.

```java
for ( LocalDateTime input : inputs )
{
    Optional < TimeSlot > hit = timeslots.stream().filter( timeSlot -> timeSlot.contains( input ) ).findAny();
    if ( hit.isEmpty() ) { resultingTimeSlots.add( new TimeSlot( UUID.randomUUID() , input , input.plusHours( 1 ) ) ); }
}
```

## Tracking appointments

If you are trying to make a future appointment tracking app, yours is the wrong approach.

You should track only the start as a `LocalDateTime`, not the end. Instead of an end, track the length of the appointment as a `Duration` object. And crucially, add a field for the time zone (`ZoneId`) as the intended context for this date and time.

The concept to understand is that political time, as opposed to natural time, varies. Days are not necessarily 24 hours long. They may be 23, 23.5, 25, or other number of hours. So a 1 hour appointment might start at 2 but end at 4.

When you need to build a schedule of moments, specific points on the timeline, apply the time zone to the start. And add duration for the end.

```
ZonedDateTime start = startLocalDateTime.atZone( storedZoneId ) ;
ZonedDateTime end = start.plus( storedDuration ) ;
```

But **never store these `ZonedDateTime`** objects. They would become invalid if the politicians change the rules of the time zone(s) in their jurisdictions. Politicians around the world do so with surprising frequency.

I and others have written on this subject many times on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.